# Connect Django 1.4> on Linux with MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: python, django, sql-server-2012

What is the best practice for connecting Django 1.4 and newer running on Linux with Microsoft SQL Server 2012? I'd like to know what default server collation to use as well.

My research (http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/) shows Django-PyODBC is the best solution, but they claim to support SQL Server 2000 and 2005. Their features include "Passes most of the Django test suite." I'm really looking for something that works and will be maintained with the future releases of django that will require python3.

I also see that http://tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/ is well researched, but doesn't include a Django DB backend module recommendation.

Please let me know what to do.

Comment: `django-mssql` works on Windows only (as I'm sure you know) because it requires pywin32.dll. just thought I'd add it to your list of bad ideas.